# How do you gracefully select() on sockets that could be closed on another thread?

Tags: c, sockets

I have a situation where a thread is selecting on sockets that are managed by a separate thread.

When a socket is closed, `select()` presumably returns that socket as "available", and it isn't until I try to read from it that I realize that it is closed.

But I'm seeing a paradox: when the socket is closed from the other thread, the system is free to reallocate its file descriptor for other purposes. (I think.)

How can I be guaranteed that by the time I read from the socket (just a numeric descriptor) the system hasn't already recycled that descriptor and used it for a new socket? In other words, for all I know I might be reading from some other socket that has been recently opened (perhaps a socket I shouldn't even be including in my `select()`!) instead of the just-closed socket.

I could keep a list of recently closed descriptors, but I'm wondering if there is a better way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short answer: Don't close sockets from another thread, that you're reading from in this one!

The FD could, potentially, be reassigned. But you *will* have problems if you're reading from one FD in multiple threads without some kind of scheme to communicate between them. Now, if you have a "Socket description" structure in shared memory that has a control semaphore and some indications of the FD, and other status information, maybe that could be manageable, but I think you'll discover that the simplest solution is almost always to make FD's specific to a single thread…

Comment: If a blocking socket is being used, closing the socket from another thread is usually the only way to unblock a blocking operation, especially if the remote endpoint of the connection is not closed gracefully so the blocking operation does not detect the closure right away and becomes deadlocked until the local endpoint is closed.

Comment: I'd (perhaps blindly) assumed that the OP was using non-blocking I/O due to the reference to `select`, but yes; in such cases, one would have to use semaphores or similar (shared vars between threads, perhaps) to signal the closure; in which case, the "reader" thread should immediately check that after every operation and "bail out" if the "closed" flag/semaphore is set…

Comment: @BRPocock, you are correct that I am using non-blocking I/O. I think you are correct that I am going to have to unify these socket operations so that they always occur from a single thread. I'm thinking about possibly selecting on something other than a socket for control messages.

Comment: Right - this is a classic *"Doctor, it hurts when I do this / Then don't do that!"* situation.

Comment: Perhaps if you can explain what you wanted to do with the alternate threads, we might be able to assist better?

Comment: @BRPocock, thanks but it's best if I don't go into that. ;-) The sockets are proxies for data transfer occurring using another protocol in the other thread, which uses its own special structures. Since the other protocol manages the structures the sockets are associated with, but not any of the socket data transfer, that's why they were originally grouped together. Now I'm working on unwinding it all and possibly using `pipe(2)` to notify the thread doing the `select()` about the lifecycle of the sockets.

Comment: Adding a `pipe()` to the FDs I select on and using it for control messages (rather than trying to juggle sockets on two separate threads) solved my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of ways to do this, here's a couple of other ideas for you.  The idea of both though, is for the owner of the socket (i.e. the thread to do the close, not another thread).

Add a control socket to your read set in the select call, e.g. unix socket.  Write some control data to break that thread from its select call.  Thread can then check if the socket should be closed or not.  Could do this as part of your socket structure or even as the actual data of your control packet.

e.g.

```
fd_set readSet;
FD_ZERO(&readSet);
FD_SET(sock, &readSet);
FD_SET(controlSock, &readSet);

int n = select(maxfd, &readSet, NULL, NULL);
...
if (FD_ISSET(controlSock, &readSet)) {
    /* check if sock should be closed or not, also drain controlSock */
}
```

then just write to the control socket to signal it to close.

You could also call signal, that would normally break a blocking IO call.  Unless they get restarted automatically.  Calls will return -1 and errno would be set to EINTR.  You could check a flag to see if you should close and break out of the call.

e.g.

```
if (n == -1 && errno == EINTR)
    goto cleanup;
```

Comment: This is essentially what I ended up doing; I did need an extra calculation to be sure my `maxfd` was correct, since I couldn't be sure if my control fd would be larger than the sockets I selected.

Comment: would you please emphasize a bit about how does that control socket get initialized? an external link would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

if you know which thread is accessing which socket, you could terminate, or at least set a flag in, the thread before closing the socket from another thread. Then the file descriptor cannot be reused for a new connection while you are still using the old connection.

Comment: There are only two or three threads; it's not a thread per socket. So terminating threads is not an option. Setting flags won't work because the thread that would be able to set/read the flags isn't the thread doing the `select()`, therefore `select()` still could have read from the wrong file descriptor. (Thanks for the response anyway.)

Answer (score 0):

If you close a socket and then call `select` with the closed socket fd set in any of the fdsets, select will return immediately with EBADF, so don't do that.

If you want to have multiple threads managing a common pool of sockets and handling them cleanly, you'll need to use some sort of lock to ensure that one thread doesn't close a socket while another thread is calling select.  If you have global fd_sets that keep track of which sockets are 'live' you can use a reader/writer lock to guard access to the set.  Aquire a read lock just before copying the set and calling select; release the lock after select returns.  Acquire a write lock before closing a socket, then release it after removing the now closed socket from the fd_set.

Another possibility is to use atomic read-modify-write instructions to manipulate the global fd_set and then when you want to close a socket, you first remove it from the global fd_set and then wait long enough for all threads to make progress before actually closing it.  This gives you a race condition (another thread might copy the global fd_set just before you remove the closing fd, and not call select until afterwards) so you need to know how long to wait is long enough, which depends on your system.

Comment: Good point about `EBADF`, but this isn't the issue. At the time when I do the `select()` I know all the FDs are valid. With a locking mechanism, `select()` still wakes up to a potentially changed socket. I would have needed to set up locking, and data structures to track metadata about if I had closed particular sockets or not. And it would be hard to know if my metadata was stale because the sockets could be reused. (So data structures would need to be particularly complex compared to `int` sockets.) The `pipe()` based IPC approach with single-threaded `read()/close()` management was simpler.

Answer (score 0):

The better way to work here would be:

Work with Non-blocking sockets (O_NONBLOCK).

Make your API such that you can add callback functions for every FD you are adding in the select() call.

```
MultiplexAdd(fd, callbackFn);
```

Now whenever the socket is ready for I/O, your callback will be called, you can do whatever you want.(Even close the socket).

Thus you can handle your sockets in a systematic way in a single thread.

Sample Code:

```
int f1()
{
    MultiplexAdd(fd1, callbackFn1);
    MultiplexAdd(fd2, callbackFn2);

    MultiplexMainLoop(); /* This is where you will be blocked on select() */
}


void callbackFn1(int fd)
{
     /* Processing as desired */
     close(fd);
     MultiplexRemove(fd); /* Remove fd from select, else select will return -1 
                                                                    with EABDF */
}
```

Even if you are stuck that you have to go for a situation where you have to close the socket from other thread, then you can create a `pipe` and add that to the `select()` as well.

Do a `write()` from you were closing the socket. In the callback to the pipe `pipeReadCb()`, you can close the socket.