# What causes bad file descriptor error with async_write?

Tags: c++, sockets, asynchronous, boost, boost-asio

I am using boost asio for a client server application and ran into this problem, with this not so informative error message(at least to me ;)), I am sending structs as messages to and fro, the sending works perfectly well from the client side, but almost similar attempt from the server's side causes this problem(rather error) : `Send failed: Bad file descriptor`

here's a snippet of the sending part ( please ask for any other details required in the comments):

```
void read_from_ts(const char*  buf, int len) {  // this is the read callback function
    if (len <= 0) {
        std::cerr << "Error: Connection closed by peer. " << __FILE__ << ":" << __LINE__ << std::endl;
        tcp_client_.close(tcp_connection_);
        tcp_connection_ = nullptr;
        ios_.stop(); // exit
        return;
    }

    const UserLoginRequest *obj = reinterpret_cast<const UserLoginRequest *>(buf);
    int tempId = obj->MessageHeaderIn.TemplateID;
    Responses r;
    switch(tempId)
    {
      case 10018: //login
        const UserLoginRequest *obj = reinterpret_cast<const UserLoginRequest *>(buf);

        //std::cout<<"Login request received"<<"\n";
        boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket sock_(ios_);
        r.login_ack(sock_);

        /*will add more*/
    }

    std::cout << "RX: " << len << " bytes\n";
  }

  class Responses
  {
    public:
      int login_ack(boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket& socket)
      {
        //std::cout<<"here"<<"\n";
        UserLoginResponse info;
        MessageHeaderOutComp mh;
        ResponseHeaderComp rh;

        rh.MsgSeqNum = 0; //no use for now
        rh.RequestTime = 0; //not used at all
        mh.BodyLen = 53; //no use
        mh.TemplateID = 10019; // IMP

        info.MessageHeaderOut = mh;
        info.LastLoginTime  = 0;
        info.DaysLeftForPasswdExpiry = 10; //not used
        info.GraceLoginsLeft = 10; //not used
        rh.SendingTime = 0;
        info.ResponseHeader = rh;
        //Pad6 not used
        async_write(socket, boost::asio::buffer(&info, sizeof(info)), on_send_completed);
      }
      static void on_send_completed(boost::system::error_code ec, size_t bytes_transferred) {
          if (ec)
              std::cout << "Send failed: " << ec.message() << "\n"; //**error shows up here**
          else
              std::cout << "Send succesful (" << bytes_transferred << " bytes)\n";
      }
  };
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE** Just noticed a third, trivial explanation when reading your code, see added bullet

Typically when the file-descriptor is closed elsewhere.

If you're using Asio, this typically means

- the `socket`¹ object was destructed. This can be a beginner error when the code doesn't extend the lifetime of objects for the duration of asynchronous operations
- the file-descriptor was passed to other code that closed it (e.g. using `native_handle(https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_stream_socket/native_handle.html)` and the other code closed it (e.g. because it assumes ownership and did error-handling).
- **UPDATE** Or, it can mean your socket was never initialized to begin. In your code I read:

  ```
  //std::cout<<"Login request received"<<"\n";
  boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket sock_(ios_);
  r.login_ack(sock_);
  ```

  However, that just constructs a new socket, never connects or binds it and tries to do `login_ack` on it. That won't work because `login_ack` doesn't bind nor connect the socket and invokes `async_write` on it.

  > Did you mean to use `tcp_connection_.sock_` or similar?

> In general closing file-descriptors in third-party code is an error in multi-threaded code because it invites race conditions which will lead to arbitrary stream corruption (see e.g. [How do you gracefully select() on sockets that could be closed on another thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8480381/how-do-you-gracefully-select-on-sockets-that-could-be-closed-on-another-thread/8480445#8480445))
>
> You can use `shutdown` instead in the majority of cases

### UNDEFINED BEHAVIORS

Also, note that

- `info` doesn't have sufficient lifetime (it goes out of scope before the `async_write` would be completed
- your `login_ack` never returns a value

### Imagining Fixes

This is what I imagine surrounding code to look like, when removing the above problems.

In fact it could be significantly simpler due to the static nature of the response, but I didn't want to assume all responses would be that simple, so I went with shared-pointer lifetime:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/18a553d1138528a4)**

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/core/ignore_unused.hpp>
#include <iostream>
using boost::asio::ip::tcp;

struct MyProgram {
    boost::asio::io_context ios_;

    struct UserLoginRequest {
        struct MessageHeaderInComp {
            int TemplateID = 10018;
        } MessageHeaderIn;
    };

    struct Connection {
        tcp::socket sock_;
        template <typename Executor>
        Connection(Executor ex) : sock_{ex} {}
    };

    std::unique_ptr<Connection> tcp_connection_ = std::make_unique<Connection>(ios_.get_executor());

    struct {
        void close(std::unique_ptr<Connection> const&);
    } tcp_client_;

    struct Responses {
        static auto login_ack() {
            struct UserLoginResponse {
                struct MessageHeaderOutComp {
                    int BodyLen = 53;             // no use
                    int TemplateID = 10019;       // IMP
                } MessageHeaderOut;
                int LastLoginTime  = 0;
                int DaysLeftForPasswdExpiry = 10; // not used
                int GraceLoginsLeft = 10;         // not used
                struct ResponseHeaderComp {
                    int MsgSeqNum = 0;            // no use for now
                    int RequestTime = 0;          // not used at all
                    int SendingTime = 0;
                } ResponseHeader;
            };
            return std::make_shared<UserLoginRequest>();
        }
    };

    void read_from_ts(const char*  buf, int len) {  // this is the read callback function
        if (len <= 0) {
            std::cerr << "Error: Connection closed by peer. " << __FILE__ << ":" << __LINE__ << std::endl;
            tcp_client_.close(tcp_connection_);
            tcp_connection_ = nullptr;
            ios_.stop(); // exit
            return;
        }

        const UserLoginRequest *obj = reinterpret_cast<const UserLoginRequest *>(buf);
        int tempId = obj->MessageHeaderIn.TemplateID;

        switch(tempId) {
            case 10018: //login
                const UserLoginRequest *obj = reinterpret_cast<const UserLoginRequest *>(buf);

                //std::cout<<"Login request received"<<"\n";
                boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket sock_(ios_);
                auto response = Responses::login_ack();
                async_write(tcp_connection_->sock_, boost::asio::buffer(response.get(), sizeof(*response)),
                    [response](boost::system::error_code ec, size_t bytes_transferred) {
                        if (ec)
                            std::cout << "Send failed: " << ec.message() << "\n"; //**error shows up here**
                        else
                            std::cout << "Send succesful (" << bytes_transferred << " bytes)\n";
                    });

                /*will add more*/
                boost::ignore_unused(obj);
        }

        std::cout << "RX: " << len << " bytes\n";
      }

};

int main() {
    MyProgram p;
}
```

---

¹  (or `acceptor`/`posix::strean_descriptor`)

Comment: The linked answer is a C answer to a C question. Note that C++ has better tools to achieve the same. E.g. a `std::shared_ptr<>` is a very effective way to keep a `boost::socket` alive and open as long as at least one thread needs it.

Comment: @ MSalters I was linking the explanation of such a race.

Comment: @DEEP I just noticed that you're using `sock_` unconnected in your code. Which obviously also triggers the error. Added an **UPDATE**

Comment: Added two sources of [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) that I spotted in your code

Comment: In the interest of overkill, added compiling minimal "fix" for the problems mentioned http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/18a553d1138528a4

Comment: @sehe I used tcp_connection_.sock_, that was already connected , giving the same error

Comment: So it is likely no longer connected

Comment: Yeah that was the case indeed, thanks a lot for the informative answer @sehe